# GLSL 330 Matrix-Computation Error {No compile error}

Tags: c++, math, opengl, matrix, glsl

Edit: 
Alright got it now :D
Problem: Completly forgot glm uses colum-major matrices. Just had to change GL_TRUE, to GL_FALSE and everything is alright.

---

I try to compute my ModelMatrix with my ProjectionMatrix. Like so:

```glsl
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;


uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;   //This are the Matrixes from my cpp-app
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;        //With a debugger that can show all active uniforms i checked their values: They're right!

uniform mat4 testUni;            //Here I checked if its working when I precompute the model and perspective matrices in my source: works
mat4 viewMatrix = mat4(1.0f);

noperspective out vec4 vertColor;


mat4 MVP = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix ; //Should actually have the same value like testUni

void main() 
{


gl_Position = testUni * position ;    //Well... :) Works
gl_Position = MVP * position ;    //Well... :) Doesn't work [Just the perspective Transforn]


vertColor = position;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you move the MVP calculation inside `main()`?  Or make MVP `const`?

Comment: const MVP: white rectangle: doesn't work
inside main(): same as above main()[but without const]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the statement

> ```
> mat4 MVP = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix ; //Should actually have the same value like testUni
> ```

into `main()`. Shader execution starts at main. If you want to avoid per-vertex computations, precompute the matrix outside and supply it as a uniform.

Comment: Edited main post^^
But actually it's the same result.

And I really don't like this precomputations, b/c in my case I have to do a extra call after each draw -.-

Comment: @user1946282: With precomputation it's one call on the CPU side vs. possibly thousands of redundant computations on the GPU. If it's about just one single matrix the CPU will vastly outperform the GPU.

Comment: yeah if thats the only possibility i have, i'll precompute it on the cpu.
but my main reason against it, is that i have 2 classes for those matrices. and i don't know how to get the value of the projection matrix into the matrix that handles the modelmatrix :/

Comment: @user1946282: You just multiply them. If your matrix classes don't support matrix multiplication, they're broken. Being able to do matrix multiplication is essential for anything related to computer graphics.

Comment: hmm you misunderstood me, i don't know how to get the matrix from the other class into the class where i will finally compute it: )